# sql-Count should be only one and two

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I need to write the query

```
select count(*) cnt from tabel1,table2
where table1.a=table2.b
```

It displays count as 0 1 2

by using the above query as subquery I need to fetch the id's from table 1 where count should be only 1 and 2 .It should not ve zero in it.

Please suggest

Comment: It seems you want to group by the count some where as this would return all the row count where the column a of table1 matches with b of table2 or do you want to find any duplicate entries ?

Comment: I need to display only the ids whose count is either 1 or 2

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select a.a , count(b.b) 
from table1 a 
join table2 b
on a.a = b.b
group by a.a
having count(b.b) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
select a.id , count(*) 
from table1 a join table2 b
  on a.id = b.id
group by a.id
having count(*)  IN (1, 2)
```